# PrestaShop - Creating Tax

Tags: php, prestashop

I am making a `WebService` to create products, now that I have succeeded I am looking for a way to create a new tax, I fill in what I can but it does not create it for me!

I think that `$taxe->save();` is not known, but it seems strange to me because the product works like this.

Here is my code:

```php
$tax = new Tax();
$tax->name = "TVA FR 3%";
$tax->rate = 3;
$tax->save();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: no error appears

Comment: What precisely do you mean by _"I think that $taxe->save(); is not known"_, then? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: In product.php there is a save method, but there is not in Tax.php

Comment: Well in that case, if the function doesn't exist you should see an error or warning about it - either on the screen or in your log file, depending how your PHP system is configured. (Just make sure you haven't switched off error logging entirely!!)

Comment: Looking at the file Tax.php at line 78 there is this: `Save the object with the field deleted to true.` when to think of you.  

I'll see if I have it disabled

Comment: Have you got a link to this file then we can all look at it?

Comment: when I var_dump($tax->save()); it shows me nothing

Comment: And what did you expect it to show? It'll only show something if a) the function exists, and b) the function returns something.

Comment: Again, please provide a link to the relevant source code file where this Tax class is defined.

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/5055a

Comment: That seems to be a class called TaxCore, not Tax, so that doesn't fit with the `new Tax()` in your code sample. Does Tax inherit from TaxCore perhaps? Anyway it has a function called `historize()`, which relates to the line 78 comment you quoted, but nothing called `save()`.